# DateDiff Within 7 days

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datediff

What am I doing wrong?  I am looking for any records where snf.StartDate is 7 or less days after inp.enddate.

and DATEDIFF(day, inp.Discharge_Date, snf.[StartDate]) <= 7

Comment: Are my columns backwards or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this????

Comment: We can't give you an answer because there are 2 tables, both are unfamiliar to us. There are 2 date columns, neither of these are familiar to us either, although one column name is indicative of what it represents, for the other "start date" of what? Think it through, if you want an answer we need to know more about your data. Typically the earlier date is the first parameter to datediff.

Comment: How's this. Let's assume it's the same table.  This table has a column called StartDate (this would be a date datatype) and EndDate (this would also be a date datatype).  How would you write a where clause to find all records where the StartDate is within 7 days of the EndDate.  So If StartDate = 1/1/2017 and EndDate = 1/5/2017 then DING DING DING (show row).  If StartDate = 1/1/2017 and EndDate = 1/16/2017 then NO NO NO (don't show row).

Comment: "I am looking for any records where snf.StartDate is 7 or less days after **inp.enddate.**" Odd that `inp.enddate` doesn't appear in your code. And does it have to be _after_, i.e > 0 days?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on how to post better SQL questions. You might also benefit from [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this perhaps:

```
and ABS( DATEDIFF(day, inp.Discharge_Date, snf.[StartDate]) ) <= 7
```

Comment: Close but not looking for absolute value as it would change the date.

Comment: ? "change the date"? the result is a signed integer. so it might change the significance of the calculation but not a date. My point, really, is that I have no idea what either date is. You provide no sample data or expected result. I was guessing that perhaps the dates are backwards because order of parameters does matter to outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This will do...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,StartDate, EndDate) As DateDiff
FROM dbo.DoesntMatter
Where DATEDIFF(day,StartDate, EndDate) between -7 and 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1,Column2
FROM Table_ABC
Where DATEDIFF(day,add_on, getdate()) > 7  order by add_on asc
```